# Consume remote rest services in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, xss

I would like to consume two remote REST services (which I don´t have control over) from my AngularJS app.

**Service 1:** To authenticate myself by passing the credentials as form-data in the HTTP header using `POST` verb.

**Service 2:** To get the data in JSON format by using `GET` verb.

Using the `$http` or `$ngResource` leads to same error message in Chrome Developer console:

> OPTIONS http://remote.service.com
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Example on $http GET

```
  $http.get('http://remote.service.com').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
```

I believe this is because of XSS limitations in JavaScript? I have considered solutions like `CORS` (requires control over the remote service) and `JSONP` (only GET) but none of these will solve my problem so Im seeking tip on other solutions.

What I don´t fully understand is why calls to the very same services works fine when using REST Client Plug-in in Chrome (for instance POSTMAN) from my local machine.

Im running Express and NodeJS in the backend, if that might help.

Comment: Where is your code that is causing the issue?

Comment: Hi Matthey, please see updated code snippet in the post now.

Comment: OPTIONS is used to validate the CORS configuration prior to the actual data request.  I assume your other tools do not enforce CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of calling the remote REST service directly from the frontend app (AngularJS app), call the backend service within same origin and from backend do the remote service call (as a proxy). This solves this issue.